# Darknet - Is it possible to load multiple weight files?

Tags: darknet, yolov5, yolov4

I have several different .weight files that were outputted in training. The reason I did this, is I noticed the model trained better with fewer classes than if I combined all 35 together. Could it possible to loop through code and have multiple model.load_weights()?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code, but I can say, that you can try to create multiple class instances of the model class, each of them with their own weights and configs, and than run each of them in the way you want